# Symfony3 Doctrine : Transaction that doesn't stop on errors

Tags: symfony, transactions, doctrine

By default, when there is an error, the transaction rolls everything back. I'd like it to log errors without any rollback. Is it possible ?

For the moment I'm flushing in the foreach loop and of course it is very long to insert thousands of lines into the DB. But I really need to log **everything** : either when it **succeeds** or not, **details about the current line being treated**, if the error was raised by php because of **data validation failure** or if it's a **DB error**, like a `UniqueConstraintViolationException` (because the script can potentially be run multiple times).

Is there a way to do this with a transaction ? Or is there any other way to do it ?

Here is what I have so far. It does exactly what I want but as expected it is a very long and costly operation :

```
    // $data is the content of the file
    foreach ($data as $key => $project) {
        // Validate data in the CSV file
        $project = $this->validateData($project);

        $newProject
            ->setStatus($project['Status'])
            ->setSiteName($project['SiteName'])
            // .....
            ;

        // Update if necessary
        $this->getManager()->merge($newProject);

        // Catch errors during DB save
        try {
            $this->getManager()->flush();
            $data[$key]['ImportStatus'] = 'imported';
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof UniqueConstraintViolationException) {
                $data[$key]['ImportStatus'] = 'already imported';
            } else {
                $message = $e->getMessage();

                $errors[] = $message;
                $data[$key]['ImportStatus'] = 'rejected';
                $data[$key]['RejectionCause'] = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $message);
            }

            // After every error the Manager is closed, reset it....
            $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->resetManager();

            // ... so we can open it again
            $this->setManager($this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Whole idea of transaction is  to run  whole sql code  or  none  of it(rollback)**.

AFAIK It's not  possible to only log errors within transaction.

You should  focus on fact  why errors showing up, not on  bypassing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not trying to bypass the error. On the contrary I want to log everything : either when data from the CSV is incorrect or when the record already exists in the DB.

Comment: Hmm   So  you should check data before trying tu put them in db . And for logging  monolog  is  great and powerfull (but configuration is painfull )

Answer (score 0):

Would like to try all insert statements even after some statements fail (e.g. then you will try failed statements after modification based on the result)? In that case I don't think the use of transaction is adequate because of its nature, as Michal explained before. You could make a loop to insert and persist and output the log for all errors caught in each insert.

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($data as $line){
    try{
        // create $entity from $line
        $em->persist($entity);
        $cnt++;
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
        // output log with the content of the inserted data, for the later use
    }
    if ($cnt%100 == 0){
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
    }
}
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

In this example I put flush statements for every 100 statements since flushing for every line is too costly but doing it at once sometimes might cause another performance problem or memory leak(I think you should experiment with it).

[bulk insert](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your code every validation errors would be caught indeed but if there is a `UniqueConstraintViolationException` I wouldn't be able to log on which line of the data the error occurred, and the execution would stop there.

Comment: If the unique constraint is in a limited column, duplication can be removed in advance by scanning the key column in $data array(you could output error or warn log for that record).

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple connections to same DB, nested transactions (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/transactions.html) or try/catch to catch rollback exception and then insert info about error to DB.